# Не могу установить модуль в python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь установить модуль через pip (абсолютно любой, пробовал bs4, reqests, openpyxl). Не получается, выдает вот такое:

> Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authent
>   ication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Pr
>   oxy filter is denied.  )'))': /simple/openpyxl/
>     Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement openpyxl (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for openpyxl

Как я понимаю блокирует рабочий прокси сервер. Скачиваю дистрибутив пакета с PyPi, и пытаюсь поставить его напрямую

```
py -3 -m pip install openpyxl
```

и тут, как я понимаю, подключение к интернету не нужно, но мне все равно выкатывает такую же ошибку :

> Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authent
>   ication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Pr
>   oxy filter is denied.  )'))': /simple/jdcal/
>     Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jdcal (from openpyxl==2.6.2) (from version
>   s: )

Вопрос такой, как установить модули не входящие в стандартную библиотеку?

Comment: Я предварительно ничего не скачиваю. Нахожу на PyPi нужную библиотеку, копирую строку для скачивания, например, pip install numpy, и вставляю ее в консоль. Библиотека, как понимаю, в этом случае загружается с Интернета.

Comment: @Irina, вроде бы в вопросе ясно написано, что такой способ у автора по какой-то причине не  работает.

Comment: В каком виде скачиваете дистрибутив нужного пакета?

Comment: это кстати, что за команда такая - ``py -3 -m pip``?

Comment: @Эникейщик дистрибутив нужного пакета в формате tar.gz. Команду я увидел в книге Пола Берри 'Программируем на пайтон', там в одной из глав создается собственный модуль в три шага:
1.Создание модуля
2.Упаковка в дистрибутив tar.gz
3.Установка модуля,
Я сразу скачал tar.gz и воспользовался командой из книги, для установки в виндоус. Причем когда я ставлю собственный модуль он ставится, а когда скачиваю с PyPi, то он выдает то что я писал выше.

Answer (score 2):

Для указания прокси:

```
pip install --proxy https://username:pwd@proxy:port package_name
```

---

Или:

```
set http_proxy=http://username:pwd@proxy:port
set https_proxy=https://username:pwd@proxy:port
pip install package_name
```

---

Или:

```
cd "%APPDATA%/pip"
notepad pip.ini
# add:
[global]
trusted-host = pypi.python.org
               pypi.org
               files.pythonhosted.org
proxy = http://[domain name]%5C[username]:[password]@[proxy address]:[proxy port]
# Сохранить и закрыть pip.ini

pip install package_name
```

---

Или:

Установить [Cntlm Authentication Proxy](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cntlm/files/latest/download?source=files), используя инструкции, например, [здесь](https://gist.github.com/sfabijanski/efcd7ca3e8c52edd5425). Для установки и использования права администратора - **не нужны**

После этого использовать прокси 127.0.0.1:3128

Лучше всего скачать zip-версию программы. На данный момент это версия [0.92.3](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cntlm/files/cntlm/cntlm%200.92.3/cntlm-0.92.3-win32.zip/download)

После этого распаковать её, настроить `.ini` файл и запускать из Git Bash окружения (программа использует Cygwin):

```
/c/tools/cntlm/cntlm.exe -c /c/tools/cntlm/cntlm.ini -I -f
```

`-I` запускает приложение в интерактивном режиме. При этом не нужно прописывать пароль в .ini - строку с паролем следует закомментировать. Программа спросит пароль при запуске

`-f` оставляет приложение на переднем плане, позволяя закрыть его по `Ctrl-Break`

Этот подход наиболее правилен с точки зрения безопасности хранения и передачи пароля по сети в открытом виде.

P.S. На моей Windows 10 программа вполне себе запустилась из командной строки безо всяких Git Bash и Cygwin...

---

Для первых трёх вариантов:

Если в имени или пароле есть спецсимволы, то их можно escape при помощи `\` или записывая в 16-ричной нотации, например, `%5C`

Answer (score 1):

### Файл .whl

Если модуль скачан в файле формата .whl, то устанавливается он так:

```
pip install module_name.whl
```

Запускать команду нужно из папки, где лежит файл `module_name.whl` или же указывать полный путь (абсолютный или относительный:

```
pip install D:/path/to/module_name.whl
```

### Файл .tar.gz

Если модуль скачан архивом `module_name.tar.gz`, то нужно распаковать архив до самого конца (должны быть папки `module_name`, `module_name.egg-info` и разные файлы, включая `setup.py`) и в папке, где это все лежит, запустить команду

```
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

В итоге установил openpyxl. Программа из ответа где указан способ замены прокси не установилась (просит права администратора которых конечно же у меня нет), а по другому я делать не стал, испугался политики по безопасности компании. Получилось сделать только так: Скачал Openpyxl с PyPi в формате tar.gz, распаковал его до конца как написано в ответе, в консоли зашел в папку там запустил python setup.py install, установка пошла но оборвалась на моменте подкачки других модулей в частности et_xmlfile(не дал скачать прокси сервер), тут я пошел на PyPi скачал et_xmlfile и установил его таким же образом. Снова повторил операцию установки openpyxl, следом он оборвался на подкачке другого модуля, скачал его установил и т.д пока в ручную не поставил все дополнительные модули и не увидел корректного завершения установки. Всем спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Я уточнил свой ответ по cntlm. На самом деле её можно использовать без прав администратора и даже без записи пароля где бы то ни было. Безопасники - торжествуют!